# Erro Com Conexão no Banco phpMyAdmim(Novo Código) Nada está resolvendo

Tags: php, html, select, sql-insert

Olha, eu não sei ao certo por onde começar mas, enfim...  possuo a pagina postada abaixo, e já verifiquei algumas com erros no banco e inserção de dados no mesmo. O código foi feita para caso haja algum tipo de erro ele indique durante a execução da página... Porém, ele mostra nenhum erro perante inserção, e quando vou tentar verificar o banco , não a nada lá.. oque pode ser?

Classe principal:

```
<div id="boxes">

<!-- Janela Modal com caixa de diálogo -->  
<div id="dialog1" class="window">
  <div class="d-header">

    <form method="POST" action="?go=cadastrar">
    <img src="imagem.png">
        <h3>Digite seu E-mail e comece GRÁTIS !!</h3>
        <label>Consiga agora o incrível programa que irá lhe ajudar!</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required value="E-mail" 
placeholder="E-mail" onclick="this.value=''" maxlength="60" /></a><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="Enviado">
        <input type="submit" name="cadastro" id="cadastro" value="Cadastrar" 
onclick="javascript:window.open('download.php?file=apostila_JAVA.pdf')"/>
<br/>

        <a href="http://echef.teccitystore.com.br/downloads.html" 
name="fechar">Fechar[x]</a>
    <img src="logo.png">
 </form>
  </div>
  <div class="d-blank"></div>
</div>
<!-- Fim Janela Modal com caixa de diálogo -->  
</div>

<!-- Máscara para cobrir a tela -->
  <div id="mask"></div>


 <?php
if(isset($_GET['go'])){
    //isset-> informa que a variável foi iniciada
    if($_GET['go'] == 'cadastrar'){

        $email = $_POST['email'];

        if(empty($email)){
                echo"<script>alert('Campo está vazio');history.back();
</script>";
        }else{ 

            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "tecci825_echef");

            if ($mysqli->connect_errno){
                die('Could not connect');
                exit();
            }   
            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downloads(email) 
WHERE email = '$email'");      
            $row = $result->fetch_row();
            if ($row[0] > 0) {
                echo "<script>alert('Email ".$email." já existente !!');
</script>";
            } else {
                $mysqli->query("Insert into downloads (email) values 
('".$email."')");
                echo "<script>alert('Cadastro para ".$email." realizado com 
sucesso!!');</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
  ?>
```

Com a ajuda das pessoas que quiseram me ajudar, este é o novo código, porém mesmo assim, não aparece nenhum resultado no banco.

Comment: Não existe não.. Estou fando de algo diferente... você não entende.. aquilo não resolve meu problema

Comment: Enchendo de `@` no código não exibir nenhum erro mesmo este é o proposito . Essas funções (`mysql_*` já foram removidas do php7 e não deveriam ser usadas. O primeiro passo é remover todas as `@` do código.

Comment: Se remover irá aparecer vários e vários erros.. de tags como mysql.. e mysqli estao fora de moda

Comment: Tem vários erros ... o que é `$_GET['$link']` e da onde vem? pq vc passa `$_GET['$link']` como conexão em `mysql_query()`? `$_GET['$email']` não seria `$_POST['email']`?

Comment: Se você simplesmente ignora os erros, claramente eles não vão ser resolvidos. Não é uma questão de moda, é uma questão de usabilidade.

Comment: Porém se retirar os "@", e deixar apenas os comandos irá dar erro pois tags como mysql_query, não estão sendo mais usadas... estou tentando procurar outro modo de usar tags diferentes com o mesmo sentido mas esta difícil de encontrar

Comment: rray, eu tentei sim... até ja fiz remoção destes erros mas o resultado continua o mesmo

Answer (score 1):

### Os erros são tantos que é melhor começar do zero

> E já que vamos começar do zero, é oportuno atualizar de mysql para mysqli, pois como todos sabemos mysql foi descontinuado. Saiba mais com [[[image]]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php/3869#3869)

```
if(isset($_GET['go'])){
    //isset-> informa que a variável foi iniciada
    if($_GET['go'] == 'cadastrar'){

        $email = $_POST['email'];

        if(empty($email)){
                echo"<script>alert('Campo está vazio');history.back();</script>";
        }else{ 

            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_BANCO");

            if ($mysqli->connect_errno){
                die('Could not connect');
                exit();
            }   
            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downloads WHERE email = '$email'");      
            $row = $result->fetch_row();
            if ($row[0] > 0) {
                echo "<script>alert('Email ".$email." já existente !!');</script>";
            } else {
                $mysqli->query("Insert into downloads (email) values ('".$email."')");
                echo "<script>alert('Cadastro para ".$email." realizado com sucesso!!');</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada por ajudar, mas ainda sim não salva no banco... oque deve estar acontecendo..>o<

Comment: então qual será o problema?, a questão de testar na mesma máquina sempre?

Comment: Eu utilizo o phpmyadmin, mas não insere nada..